# Parse a matrix in a textfile into an actual (array-based) matrix in python?

Tags: python, parsing, matrix

I am trying to parse a textfile where a matrix is saved in the string format:
"[[0,1],[1,0]]"

To goal is to parse the .txt file and turn it into an actual matrix represented by an arrays of arrays stored in some variable.
I am new to python and programming in general and can't think of an nice way to do this.

I only need help with how to construct the python matrix from what we get in the .txt file.

Comment: As stated in the above link, `eval("[[0,1],[1,0]]")` is the solution.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for this simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Kraigolas, the python eval() function will evaluate that expression and
convert it to a Python list of lists.

To elaborate further, if you want to then work with it as a matrix, your best bet is to
then convert it to a NumPy array.

This can be a one liner:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(eval("[[0,1],[1,0]]"))
```

You then can work with arr using NumPy as you wish.